# What is the right way to make bindings between model and viewmodel in MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I used couple of days to refine my MVVM application, but i came to a point where I actually didn't know what will be the correct way.

What is the correct way of making binding in mvvm?

**Option one:**

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

     public CustomerViewModel(Customer c)
     {
      _customer = c;
     }

     private readonly Customer _customer;

     public string CustomerName
     {
       get { return _customer.Name; }
       set
          { 
           _customer.Name = value;
           RaisePropertChanged("CustomerName");
          }
     }        
}
```

**Option two**

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public CustomerViewModel(Customer c)
    {
      _customerName= c.CustomerName;
    }

    private string _customerName;

    public string CustomerName
    {
       get { return _customerName; }
       set
         {
          _customerName= value;
          RaisePropertChanged("CustomerName");
         }
     }        
}
```

Comment: Is just my opinion: I always prefer the option two. The goal of MVVM is to decouple models and view models. This mean that your view model, in this case CustomerViewModel, can have different set of properties because data to display have different behavior from your database model.

Comment: I'd say option one because otherwise the model would never be informed that the name changed. You need other constructs for that in option two

Comment: You can bind directly to the properties of customer (you don't need to redefine the properties in your view model class) if it implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: There is not the right way, there are many ways of doing it. Another one would be to keep your POCO clean with just get;set; for each property, and then have another class with exactly the same properties, but implementing on it INotifyPropertyChanged  and maybe even doing other stuff. Then you can map those two together (maybe by automapper for example), and on your view models use this new class.

Comment: Interesting everyone gives their opinion but no one really explains why both aren't suitable in most cases, since none of them track a state but directly modifies the model, which is horribly awful, because you can't undo actions. the correct way is that the viewmodel have it's own backing fields and when you call a save command, this values are updated to the underlying model and then persistence. This way you can cancel an editing of a model and non change will ever be done to the model itself, unless you hit save/apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the solutions work for you-

If you are having only one property(CustomerName) to bind to your view, then Option 1. As pointed rightly by @Default if you use Option 2 you will fail to update the value back to `Customer c` object when you change the value of `CustomerName` property.

If you need to bind all the properties of Customer. Bind the Customer object directly and make sure the Customer class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

So it will go like this -

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase{

    public CustomerViewModel(Customer c){
_customer = c;
}

private readonly Customer _customer;

public Customer Customer{
 get{return _customer;}
 set{_customer.Name = value;
   RaisePropertChanged("Customer");
 }
 }
}
public Customer:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #INotifyPropetyChanged implementation
    private string _customerName;

    public string CustomerName{
     get{return _customerName;}
     set{_customerName = value;
       RaisePropertChanged("CustomerName");
     }
}
```

Then Bind it with `CustomerViewModel.Customer.Name`

**Edit**
On a side note - again @Default rightly pointed... Make sure you separate the persistence of data from model back to database to be handled properly. i.e. Save it to database only when you click on Save button, etc.. otherwise it will make too many calls for every property change. And also the issue of multiple users updating the same view model. You just have to keep these points in mind and not to violate them.

Comment: What if you need to serialize your model later? The name would be unchanged if you only take the name from the customer and not assign it back

Comment: @Default Sorry didnt quite get you. Are you saying Option 2 will fail if its serialized? and it will be fine with Option 1?

Comment: [this is what I mean](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zmxf63). If the string is copied the customer is never notified when the name changes in the viewmodel

Comment: I feel dumb... I didn't read it properly. Thanks for pointing out. I will update my answer.

Comment: Weell, there is a reason I am aware of this issue.. :) However, do note that you might not *want* to assign back. You might have a viewmodel that shouldn't interact with the model until a `Save` button is pushed or something like that. There could be multiple viewmodels interacting with the same model and you need other mechanics to synchronize state. The OP isn't making that very clear. It all really depends on the requirements.

Comment: True... even my updated answer wont address that :). Thanks for the clarification. I always overlook this because we have a separate layer which is used for persisting the data back to database. Hence took it for granted.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation :)

Comment: don't bind it with `CustomerViewModel.Customer.Name` - you're exposing the model to the view and that is not correct, because the view isn't supposed to be aware of the model. The `Customer` should be internal state for the ViewModel and it should be the ViewModels task to decide how the model should be modified (you could have other logic in the viewmodels setters). With that said, you still need to map the properties in the viewmodel and bind to the viewmodels properties.

Comment: So what you are saying is that. If the view depends on the Model directly, any changes to the Model will have an impact on the view and break it. Say if I replace `Customer.Name` tomorrow with a different property name, it will break the view. But if this is handled by the viewmodel then its viewmodel's responsibility rather than view's responsibility. Good point! Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: It's not about change in the model, it's rather about state. The model is a dumb object, it should only hold state. If you tomorrow decide that any changes to the model should impact some other data object you have to implement that somewhere. That somewhere is in the viewmodel, not the model. By binding directly to the model you bypass the viewmodels opportunity to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting question, how to handle plain objects in WPF applications. From one hand, typically you don't want to add INPC and other UI related stuff to your business objects, because they may be used in other parts of the application, that have nothing to do with WPF. From the other hand, creating separate ViewModels that will have lots of in common with plain objects is a big overhead. Recently I've seen a great course on Pluralsight exactly on this topic:
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-mvvm-advanced-model-treatment/description

Author sticks to **option one** approach, when POCO objects are wrapped by view models, that in turn implement INPC and IDataErrorInfo interfaces, track changes etc. 
Author suggests to use T4 templates for creating a VM wrapper for each POCO object. Logic in T4 templates with the help of reflection extracts properties from plane objects and generate wrapper properties in corresponding VMs. Interesting approach, worth of trying.

Answer (score 0):

In general I used Option 2 in MVVM and automapper to map a model to a view model and the other way around. I think it all depends what you want to do with the VM and how big the differences are.

In the projects I worked on the VM class contained more fields and logic and it was more comfortable to work directly with properties of the VM rather than the properties of an object property like you would in Option 1: `CustomerViewModel.Customer.Name`